# Repeater for LineSeries in a chart

Tags: qt, charts, delegates, qml, repeater

I have a `ChartView` with two defined `ValueAxis` and would like to display multiple `QLineSeries`. The data are passed from c++ side (through the `cxxDataProxy.mySeriesList` object below) as `QVariantList::append(QVariant::fromValue(QLineSeries*))` so they should appear as list on the JavaScript side. Whenever the series changes, I would like to create one `LineSeries` in the chart for each `QLineSeries` in the list.

My naive attempt was like this:

```
ChartView{
    id: _myChartView
    ValueAxis { id: _valueAxis_X }
    ValueAxis { id: _valueAxis_Y }
    Repeater{ 
        id: _lineSeriesRepeater
        model: cxxDataProxy.mySeriesList
        Component{
            id: lineSeriesDelegate 
            LineSeries {
                name: "series #"+index.toString()
                axisX: _valueAxis_X
                axisY: _valueAxis_Y
            }
        }
    }
}
```

hoping that any change in `mySeriesList` (the property has change notification) will cause the list of `LineSeries` to be re-build by the repeater. What I hit when the list actually changes is:

```
QML Component: Delegate must be of Item type
```

I saw something very similar asked at Qt forum in [QML, create LineSeries at runtime](https://forum.qt.io/topic/86192/qml-create-lineseries-at-runtime) which went unanswered.

Thanks for suggestions!

**PS** [This post](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/67656-Adding-right-axis-in-QtQuick-ChartView-changes-also-left-axis) adds line series dynamically using JavaScript callback. The code create series and then copies data point-by-point. Is there perhaps a more direct way, more elegant, more readable, more maintainable?

Comment: QLineSeries will have the same number of elements? On the other hand I do not think it's possible to use Repeater since it only allows graphic elements, if the answer is yes to my initial question then my solution is very similar to the one proposed in the link that you point out but a little cleaner

Comment: There are several ways to create `LineSeries` dynamically but the approach is always based on removing all previous series using `removeAllSeries()` and then adding new ones using `createSeries()` in the loop. But I would ask the question differently: what is your target? For what you need recreate the series (besides the fact that this is a very expensive operation)? Wouldn't be better to update only points in the series using `at(index)` and then `replace()`?

Comment: @folibis: new measurements need to be added to the plot (as they are coming from outside), each with different color and legend entry. This typically happens quite rarely (once in a few 10s of seconds at most) and there is about 100 points in each line.